# How To Create A Central Auth Project In GCP/Firebase?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform

So what Im trying to do is, create a central project that holds all auth credentials and base user information in Firestore. Then have other projects connect to that project to gain access to individual apps. An example of this would be the following:

Project A - Auth Project
Project B - App 1
Project C - App 2

Project B Authentication -> Project A Authenticate And Give Project B Firestore User Object
Project C Authentication -> Project A Authenticate And Give Project C Firestore User Object

Anyone have any idea how I can do this? I have an idea that I may be able to do it with Firebase functions but can I also do it from the frontend such as from an iOS app? Would that require two Firebase Config files? If so how do I differentiate between the two of them in the iOS app?

A little more context on this. I am finished creating my first app. I am beginning to create an app that is completely different from the first app but I need my users to be able to share credentials across both apps. So my plan is to create a single project that holds the master user record and authenticates users from both of the other projects. Does this make sense? Also users will only authenticate using email/password combo, nothing else.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check these official documentation on [how to configure multi projects](https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/multiprojects) and [understanding the firestore app and projects in detail](https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/learn-more#projects-apps-products)As,any Firebase project is governed by the Firestore security rules basically implement the security model which does refuse data or accounts outside of the project where they were deployed.You can try to implement with some backend API which can communicate between the two systems maintaining these security constraints.Also,If you want users from project B and project C to share credentials which have been authenticated in project A and you can let the user authenticate with the same UID with a "parallel" account in the second project rules on B would still be limited to the app and data for the immediate project and would not be able to access anything directly into other one.
I recommend you to check the following examples for the similar approach:

- [Use Firebase auth data and users for multiple project and apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68597529/use-firebase-auth-data-and-users-for-multiple-projects-and-apps)
- [Single firebase project for multiple GCP projects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67367661/can-i-use-a-single-firebase-project-for-multiple-google-cloud-projects)
- [Implementing cross project user authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64719348/implementing-cross-project-user-auth-single-sign-on-like-google-account-using)

Comment: You are right. I cant believe as many times as I looked at that exact document it didn't make sense until you pointed it out. Thank you.

Comment: I am glad it helped you with the issue.